# Vírgulas em orações subordinadas causais, finais e temporais

Tags: pontuação, vírgula, orações-subordinadas

Em frases com orações subordinadas causais, finais e temporais, lendo [este post sobre Pontuação](http://livrodeestilo.blogs.sapo.pt/187010.html) do blogue [Livro de Estilo](http://livrodeestilo.blogs.sapo.pt/), as vírgulas utilizam-se conforme a posição dessas orações na frase. Se for no início ou no meio, levam obrigatoriamente vírgula; no fim, não. Penso, porém, que neste último caso não será gramaticalmente incorreto utilizar a vírgula, embora seja menos frequente.

Exemplos de orações causais retirados do post:

> - posição inicial (com vírgula): Porque estava a chover, resolvi ficar em  casa.
> - posição medial (com vírgula a delimitar o início e o fim): Resolvi, porque estava a chover, ficar em casa.
> - posição final (sem vírgula): Resolvi ficar em casa porque estava a chover.

A minha questão é a de saber se se pode também escrever

> - Resolvi ficar em casa, porque estava a chover.

ou

> - Resolvi ficar em casa, para acabar o trabalho. (oração final)
> - A sr.ª D. Irene já tinha saído da quinta, quando foi procurada para entrar no convento de Santa Clara de Coimbra. (oração temporal)

em vez de, respectivamente,

> - Resolvi ficar em casa para acabar o trabalho.
> - A sr.ª D. Irene já tinha saído da quinta quando foi procurada para entrar no convento de Santa Clara de Coimbra.

que são outros exemplos do mesmo post.

*Aditamento 1*: Tanto quanto é do meu entendimento, quando a oração subordinada antecede a principal, separam-se ambas por uma vírgula. A minha dúvida refere-se ao caso em que a subordinada fica no fim da frase.

*Aditamento 2*: Outros exemplos já dados anteriormente, em comentário(s) meu(s) a esta questão. De «Gramática Portuguesa» para a antiga 4.ª classe, de Tomás de Barros:

1. «Perdoa-lhe**,** **porque não soube o que fez**»;
2. «Estimai**,** **para que vos estimem**»;
3. «O comboio já tinha partido**,** **quando chegámos à estação**».

Mas também:

4. «Pasteur foi um sábio de grande coração **porque descobriu a cura da raiva**».

E de «Breve Gramática do Português Contemporâneo», de Celso Cunha e Lindley Sintra:

5. «Não veste com luxo **porque o tio não é rico**»;
6. «Viera um vestido de marca**,** **para que a vestissem com ele**».

Comment: Isto é motivado por uma preferência pelo uso da vírgula, ou mera curiosodade?

Comment: Na verdade, com algumas locuções conjuntivas, parece-me necessária a vírgula, mesmo que a oração causal esteja no fim: "vamos ao banho uma vez que está calor." Sem vírgula não sabemos se é "vamos ao banho, uma vez que..." ou "vamos ao banho uma vez, que..."

Comment: @Jacinto Não é uma mera curiosidade. Quanto à preferência pelo uso da vírgula, posso dizer que não se trata disso. Consultando, agora, a "Gramática Portuguesa" de Tomás de Barros que era usada na antiga 4.ª classe, vejo exemplos como: 1. Perdoa-lhe **, porque não soube o que fez**; 2. Estimai **, para que vos estimem**; 3. O comboio já tinha partido **, quando chegámos à estação**. Mas também: 4. Pasteur foi um sábio de grande coração **porque descobriu a cura da raiva**.(continua)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vírgula poderá de facto ser usada para separar orações subordinadas adverbiais pospostas, mas arriscamo-nos a alterar o sentido da frase (de forma a que ela possa deixar de ser lida como subordinada adverbial), ou, no mínimo, a alterar o foco da frase.

> Resolvi ficar em casa, porque estava a chover.

Comparando com a versão sem vírgula, este *porque* parece explicativo e não causal. Ou seja, transformaste **subordinação** em **coordenação**. A frase passa então a ser equivalente a:

> Resolvi ficar em casa, [pausa] que/pois estava a chover.

[Esta resposta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/valores-causal-e-explicativo-de-porque/21014) no Ciberdúvidas admite que a vírgula possa ser usada para um "porque" causal, mas em todo o caso está-se a introduzir uma ambiguidade que da outra forma não existiria.

Vejamos então com *para*:

> Resolvi ficar em casa, para acabar o trabalho.

A versão sem vírgula e esta em cima são bem diferentes. Esta põe o foco na resolução de ficar em casa, enquanto a versão sem vírgula na razão por que se resolveu ficar em casa (mas não tanto como prepor "para acabar o trabalho").

Por fim:

> A sr.ª D. Irene já tinha saído da quinta, quando foi procurada para entrar no convento de Santa Clara de Coimbra.

O significado aqui é também diferente. Nesta versão **com** vírgula, parece se estão a apresentar dois factos relativamente independentes, em que o segundo se segue ao primeiro (aqui óbvio por causa de "já"), mas em que o primeiro dá enquadramento temporal ao segundo. Na versão **sem** vírgula, é mais fácil interpretar a oração com "quando" como oração adverbial que qualifica a outra, especialmente se movermos a oração com "quando" para o início da frase. Um exemplo análogo para a versão **com** vírgula:

> O João chegou então a casa, quando [=altura em que] se deparou com a sua mãe morta no chão.

Comment: Na parte em que escreve "especialmente se movermos a oração com "quando" para o início da frase. ", veja o meu aditamento à questão: "Tanto quanto é o meu entendimento, quando a oração subordinada antecede a principal, separam-se ambas por uma vírgula. A minha dúvida refere-se ao caso em que a subordinada fica no fim da frase."

Comment: @AméricoTavares Certo, o que quero dizer é que o significado dessas duas frases ("Quando ... , a sr.a D. Irene..." e "A sr.a D. Irene já tinha saído quando...") têm significados semelhantes, distintos daquela com "... , quando ...". Simplesmente esta diferença é mais óbvia quando temos "quando" no início.

Comment: Também vejo as coisas assim. Com uma diferençazita no primeiro exemplo. Parece-me que, mesmo com vírgula, *porque estava a chover* vai ser visto como a causa de ficar em casa. Acho que o que muda é o foco, à maneira do teu exemplo seguinte. É claro que uma causa explica a resolução de ficar em casa; o objetivo, *para acabar o trabalho*, também a explica.