# Pontuação correta e classificação de "mas tu és médico para ires lá dar palpites?"

Tags: sintaxe, pontuação, orações-subordinadas

Para que não haja dúvidas, ele não é médico mas propõe-se ir dar uns conselhos a um amigo doente. Portanto a pergunta do exemplo é retórica. Quanto à pontuação, vejo três possibilidades:

> (a) Mas tu és médico, para ires lá dar palpites?
>
> (b) Mas tu és médico para ires lá dar palpites?
>
> (c) Mas tu és médico? Para ires lá dar palpites?

Incluí a (c) só para ser exaustivo: dá ideia que o locutor não tencionava dizer "para ires lá dar palpites," e depois, num *afterthought*, resolveu dizê-lo. Mas entre (a) e (b), qual é a forma correta? Ou são as duas?

E qual é a classificação das orações? Dá-me ideia que a primeira é principal, e a segunda, subordinada (a primeira pode viver sem a segunda). Mas subordinada de que tipo? A frase parece-me semanticamente mais ou menos equivalente a:

> Mas tu és médico, que possas lá ir dar palpites?

A segunda oração desta última frase parece-me um subordinada adjetiva explicativa. Se for assim, poderíamos classificar também assim a frase original (e argumentar assim que tem que levar vírgula)?

Já existem duas perguntas e respostas sobre a separação ou não de orações por vírgula, que poderão ajudar a responder à presente questão: [vírgulas em orações subordinadas finais, causais e temporais](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/v%C3%ADrgulas-em-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-causais-finais-e-temporais) e esta outra sobre [vírgulas e orações subordinadas substantivas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/deve-se-evitar-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-entre-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-substantivas-e-a-ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p).

Comment: Eu não usaria a "b"

Comment: Parece-me que esta questão se poderá reduzir à de [Vírgulas em orações subordinadas causais, finais e temporais](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/vírgulas-em-orações-subordinadas-causais-finais-e-temporais).

Comment: É possível que sim. Mas teremos primeiro que decidir que tipo de orações constituem a frase, que é uma das coisas que eu pergunto.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Na verdade, não me parece que se reduza. Não me parece que o ***para*** introduza neste caso uma oração final. Aliás, eu inclino-me mais para a versão com vírgula aqui; ao contrário do que aconteceria se a oração fosse subordinada final.

Comment: Talvez tenha razão,  mas se não é subordinada final, será o quê?

Comment: Pois, é essa a minha pergunta.

Comment: Em linguagem falada, tudo (quase) é possível. (a) e (c) são corretas para a lingua falada.....Depende do que o autor queira dizer, né?

Comment: Eu, sinceramente acho que as 3 podem estar corretas dependendo do que queres dizer e como queres dizer.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta é a letra **b)**.

A finalidade da vírgula é organizar a frase de forma que não haja duplo sentido. Dessa forma, quando um termo é deslocado de sua *ordem direta*, ela deve ser utilizada.

Na forma mais simples, podemos dizer que a ordem direta é formada por **sujeito (quem) + predicado (o quê)**. O predicado pode ser mais complexo e formado por outros termos (verbos, complemento nominal, complemento verbal, adjunto adverbial)

Veja os exemplos abaixo.

- Ordem direta:

> Ricardo comeu a sobremesa depois do almoço.

- Ordem inversa

> Depois do almoço, Ricardo comeu a sobremesa.

Aqui, o adjunto adverbial de tempo foi deslocado para o início da frase e, obrigatoriamente, de ser separado por vírgula.

Em frases contendo mais de uma oração, ou seja, mais de um verbo, a vírgula é utilizada para separar as orações.
Exemplo:

> Fui à igreja ontem, mas não rezei.

Veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://ricardovigna.wordpress.com/estudos-de-gramatica/16-sintaxe-de-colocacao-a-ordenacao-dos-elementos-da-frase/)

Entretanto, no exemplo dado:

```
Mas tu és médico para ires lá dar palpites?
```

O termo "mas" **não** exerce papel adversativo, mas sim aditivo (poderia ser substituído por "E"). A frase está em ordem direta, sem motivos para que haja vírgula.

**Edição**
Sim, são duas orações. Mas, a segunda ("para ires lá dar palpites") é uma subordinada adverbial final e, por exercer papel de advérbio, só deve ser separada por vírgula quando deslocada de sua ordem direto.

Comment: Carlos, o problema é mais complexo. A minha frase tem duas orações. Há casos em que duas orações são separadas por vírgula: *resolvi ficar em casa, pois estava a chover* [vê aqui discussão deste tipo de frases](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/v%C3%ADrgulas-em-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-causais-finais-e-temporais). Noutros casos, não pode haver vírgula entre as orações: *peço-te que reconsideres a tua resposta* [vê aqui mais exemplos deste tipo](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/v%C3%ADrgulas-em-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-causais-finais-e-temporais)

Comment: Tem razão, Jacinto. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Carlos, a possibilidade da segunda oração ser adverbial final foi discutida nos comentários à pergunta (vê lá em cima). Eu estou um bocado cético (a finalidade de ele ser médico é ir dar palpites!?), mas não chegámos a conclusão nenhuma.

Comment: Por analogia, não vejo nenhum outro tipo mais indicado. Veja o link: https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs/Per%C3%ADodo_composto/Ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es_subordinadas/Adverbiais#Ora.C3.A7.C3.A3o_subordinada_adverbial_final

Comment: Editei a pergunta com uma sugestão.

Comment: A única reconsideração que eu proporia seria a de que o `Mas` que inicia a frase exerce, na verdade, função expletiva (bem como um `E` que o substituísse), uma vez que não adiciona por simples ausência de uma primeira oração à qual pudesse adicionar algo.

Answer (score 0):

A forma correcta é a b), no sentido da frase-chave.

Esta frase, como tantas outras é uma frase-chave (chavão). A frase é utilizada normalmente quando uma 3ª parte se intromete numa conversa alheia. Não necessariamente com "médico" (Outras Formas são Mestre, Doutor e Engenheiro) nem palpites (Bitaites). Usa-se também noutras circunstancias bastante específicas (Mas tu és cão para lá ir roer o osso? - Normalmente utilizado quando um homem tenta aproximar-se a uma mulher com segundas intenções). É uma frase feita.

> (a) Mas tu és médico, para ires lá dar palpites?

Significaria que a pessoa é **de facto médica**, que não é verdade. A pausa, ou virgula, denota essa influência.

> (c) Mas tu és médico? Para ires lá dar palpites

Não é incomum utilizar uma forma semelhante. Porém neste caso, a frase conota uma pergunta genuina, que não é o objectivo. Uma alternativa utilizando interogações seria "Mas tu **por acaso** és Médico? Para estares aí a dar palpites!", ou alternativamente, "Mas **desde quando** é que és Médico?". O Sarcasmo e a Ironia é a chave para estas expressões.

A opção B seria a mais correcta, dentro destas opções. Aqui fica uma lista de alternativas mais comuns:

> Mas tu és médico para "tares" aí a mandar palpites?
>
> Mas tu és Médico? É que estás aí a dar palpites.
>
> Olha-me este com a mania que é Médico, anda aí a mandar palpites.

Comment: Eu concordo com a explicação! Pelo menos a _b)_ é a mais comum no Brasil.

Answer (score -3):

Eu iria para a a), a virgula obriga a fazer a pausa que assenta de forma bastante subtil no processo de dicção.

Comment: Oops, parece que o pessoal não gostou da tua resposta. Até é bem possível que eu esteja de acordo com a tua ideia, mas não tenho a certeza. Seria bom que a explicasses melhor. Por exemplo, por que é que a pausa na dicção é necessária? Que diferença faria se não houvesse pausa? Vejo que acabaste de chegar ao site. Valerá a pena dares por aí uma vista de olhos para ver o nível das respostas. Em geral espera-se uma resposta mais bem fundamentada do que a tua está presentemente.