# Infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal?

Tags: concordância-verbal, sintaxe

Ao redigir [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-correta-e-classifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-mas-tu-%C3%A9s-m%C3%A9dico-para-ires-l%C3%A1-dar-palpites), hesitei entre as duas versões seguintes:

> (a) Mas tu és médico, para **ires** lá dar palpites?
>
> (b) Mas tu és médico, para **ir** lá dar palpites?

Optei pela primeira, mas não tenho a certeza. Do mesmo modo, também não estou seguro quanto a:

> Mas nós somos alguns desgraçados, para não **poder** jantar fora de vez em quando?
>
> Mas nós somos alguns desgraçados, para não **podermos** jantar fora de vez em quando?

(Também não tenho a certeza se as orações devem ser separadas por vírgula, mas isso pertence à outra pergunta.) Portanto, nos exemplos acima, devemos usar o infinitivo pessoal (*ires, podermos*) ou o impessoal (*ir, poder*)? Ou estão ambos corretos?

Comment: Também tenho minhas dúvidas sobre o infinitivo flexionado.  É muito usado no português falado, cá por estas bandas, mas em alguns casos eu acho que não se deve flexionar.  Só não me recordo agora em que situações.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesse caso, ambas são possíveis, com um significado ligeiramente diferente<sup>1</sup>:

> [...] «a escolha da forma infinitiva depende de cogitarmos somente da acção ou do intuito ou necessidade de pormos em evidência o agente da acção» (Saudi Ali)<sup>2</sup>. No primeiro caso, preferiremos o *infinitivo não flexionado*; no segundo, o *flexionado*.
>
> Trata-se, pois de um emprego selectivo, mais do terreno da estilística do que, propriamente, da gramática.

Portanto a forma impessoal concebe o "dar palpites" mais como uma atividade em abstrato e a forma pessoal particularizada ao facto de ser o interlocutor a dar palpites. Neste caso não faz muita diferença; ainda que a minha preferência seria também usar a forma pessoal e ter claramente o mesmo sujeito nas duas orações.

Noutras frases, a diferença pode ser mais marcada:

> (1) Para irmos dar lá palpites, é preciso termos lata.
>   (2) Para ir dar lá palpites, é preciso ter lata.

Analogamente às tuas frases, em que temos um agente expresso na primeira oração, se mudarmos *ter* para *termos* em (2) estamos a particularizar parcialmente a frase. Aí o significado de (2) aproximar-se-ia bastante do de (1).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra. *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*. Lisboa, 1ª ed., 1984, p. 487.</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>Saudi Ali. *Gramática secundária da língua portuguesa*, São Paulo, Melhoramentos, s./d. p. 180.</sub>

Comment: Fixe, então vou mesmo manter o infinitivo pessoal. Dirias que nos teu exemplos *para*  introduz o quê? Oração subordinada final?