# Fiquem à vontade para tirar(em) dúvidas

Tags: concordância-verbal

Qual o correto?

> Fiquem à vontade para tirar dúvidas.

ou

> Fiquem à vontade para tirarem dúvidas.

Comment: A preposição "para", nesse contexto, requer uma oração no infinitivo. Acontece que o português tem duas formas de infinitivo: uma pessoal, que flexiona-se quanto ao sujeito; e uma impessoal, que não flexiona-se e termina em **-ar/-er/-ir/-or**. Como nas duas frases que você deu de exemplo, o verbo tirar está no infinitivo (uma no pessoal e outra no impessoal), ambas estão corretas. Manterei essa resposta como comentário pois não tenho muito conhecimento em gramática para explicar a fundo, mas creio que seja essa a resposta.

Comment: Creio que já tens resposta em [infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal: "mas tu és médico, para lá ires/ir dar palpites?"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/infinitivo-pessoal-ou-impessoal)

Comment: @Jacinto De fato. Vou marcar como duplicata.

Comment: Carla, também achei que fosse duplicata, mas quis esperar para ver o que achavas, ou se querias reformular a tua. Curiosamente, eu prefiro o pessoal em "mas tu és médico, para ires lá dar palpites", mas o impessoal na tua, "estejam à vontade para tirar dúvidas". Não sei explicar porquê.

Comment: @Jacinto Como diria o mestre Guimarães: `pãos ou pães é questão de opiniães`.