# O infinitivo pessoal pode ser usado quando o pronome pessoal está atrás?

Tags: gramática, verbos, infinitivo-pessoal

A minha hipótese é que o infinitivo pessoal só poderia ser usado quando um pronome pessoal estaria atrás dele, ou talvez quando tenha que ter concordância com pronome pessoal, ou algo do gênero (desculpai pela falta de explicitude).

Exemplos:

"É pra **TU** ficares no teu quarto."; (parece-me que está se referindo a **TU**)

"É pra ficar no quarto."; (parece-me impessoal)

"Eu gosto de quebrar";

"Eu gosto de tu quebrares"; (parece-me errada)

"Eu fiquei de pé até **ELES** saírem do lugar".

Essa hipótese minha 'tá correta? Ou são apenas coincidências? Um dos motivos que eu pensei nisso é também pelo seu nome, "infinitivo **pessoal**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regra geral diz-nos que:

> 1. Usa-se o **infinitivo pessoal/flexionado** numa frase em que há duas ações e o sujeito dos dois verbos em presença é diferente.
> 2. Pelo contrário, emprega-se o **infinitivo impessoal ou não flexionado** numa frase em que há duas ações e o sujeito dos dois verbos em presença é o mesmo. [*(ver mais)*](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-o-uso-do-infinitivo-impessoal-e-pessoal/34446)

Vejamos um exemplo: «Um treino durante a manhã e, agora, tempo de descanso, com Scolari a **dar** mais algum tempo aos jogadores para **recuperar** do encontro frente a Angola»'

Neste caso, devia ter sido usado o infinitivo impessoal, pois a primeira ação, "dar", tem como sujeito "Scolari" e a segunda ação, "recuperar", refere-se aos "jogadores".

Nos exemplos da questão:

1. **É** para tu **ficares** no quarto. - Dois sujeitos ("É": sujeito nulo, "ficares": sujeito "tu")
2. **É** para **ficar** no quarto - Sujeito nulo nas duas ações
3. Eu **fiquei** de pé até eles **saírem** do lugar - Dois sujeitos ("Eu fiquei"/ "eles saírem")
4. Eu **fiquei** de pé até **sair** da sala. - Sujeito é o mesmo nas duas ações ("Eu")

Em relação a "Eu **gosto** de **quebrar**", neste caso, o verbo "quebrar" não é flexiondo porque está a a ser usado como objeto da ação "gosto" ("eu gosto de [algo]).

Ou seja, o seu palpite inicial estava correto, embora por razões algo erradas - não se trata de a frase ter ou não um pronome pessoal explícito, mas sim de ter dois ou mais sujeitos diferentes (que podem estar representados por pronomes pessoais).

Comment: Obrigado por tua resposta.

Comment: De nada! Espero que tenha ajudado

Comment: Tu acabaste de me ajudar numa outra dúvida também que eu tinha, se "quebrar" em "eu gosto de quebrar" era o objeto.

Comment: Sim, é o complemento oblíquo

Comment: Rye, e @Schilive, essa regra geral não condiz completamente com a resposta a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/infinitivo-pessoal-ou-impessoal), que dá como correto "mas **tu és** médico, para **ires** lá dar palpites" (mesmo sujeito, infinitivo pessoal).

Comment: Jacinto, eu percebi isso. Eu não fizera a minha pergunta corretamente, então eu não o quis corrigir. A minha pergunta era para ter sido "Usa-se o infinitivo pessoal sempre que for possível adicionar o pronome pessoal?".

Answer (score 0):

Salvo uma excepção em certas frases enfáticas **só** o infinitivo pessoal pode ser usado com um sujeito explícito.

Mas sem sujeito explícito, a forma a escolher depende das circunstâncias. Com a forma pessoal, pelos menos quando não se confunde com a forma impessoal, é sempre claro qual o sujeito. Mas nem sempre o verbo selecciona uma frase com o infinito pessoal -- parece-me o caso com *gostar* (*gosto de termos...* é para mim muito marginal, diria *gosto do facto de termos...*). Outras vezes o verbo admite ambas as formas, mas a forma não flexionada tem o sujeito co-referente com o sujeito ou um objeto na oração principal (*prometeste sair* é o mesmo que *prometeste saíres*, mas o sujeito de *sair* está alterado em *prometeste sairmos*); ainda outras vezes o infinito pessoal tem uma referência genérica como no teu segundo exemplo.