# "Use a imaginação para nos imaginar nos divertindo" ou "use a imaginação para nos imaginar se divertindo"?

Tags: concordância-verbal

Para facilitar-me a vida:

1. "use a imaginação para nos imaginar nos divertindo";
2. "use a imaginação para nos imaginar se divertindo".

Eu acho que 1 e 2 estão corretos. Acho que 1 estaria se referindo a "nós" e 2 não especifica, mas, por contexto, se vê que se refere a "nós" também.

Assim como em "usa o chinelo pra matares a barata" e "usa o chinelo pra matar a barata". "Matares" se refere a "tu"; mas "matar", em 2, não especifica, porém, por contexto, se refere a "tu".

Enfim, ambos estão corretos ou apenas um? Se apenas d'ambos, qual?

P.S.: eu tirei 2 dum vídeo do YouTube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXyOAHMDz7s (08:44).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só o número 1 — *nos imaginar nos divertindo* — está correto; *nos imaginar se divertindo* é agramatical.

Primeiro, *usa (tu) o chinelo para matares a barata* e *usa (tu) o chinelo para matar a barata* estão ambos corretos, porque num caso tens o infinitivo pessoal (*matares*), no outro o infinitivo impessoal (*matar*), e ambos são possíveis. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/infinitivo-pessoal-ou-impessoal). O infinitivo impessoal é *matar* em todas as pessoas, portanto podemos dizer, *eles usam o chinelo para matar baratas, nós usamos o chinelo para matar baratas*.

O *se* do exemplo em questão não é o pronome indefinido (como em *está-se bem aqui*), que não especifica. É o pronome do paradigma reflexo: *eu divirto-me, ele diverte-se, nós divertimo-nos, eles divertem-se*. Portanto, o *se* do teu exemplo especifica uma terceira pessoa (do singular ou plural). Como a pessoa imaginada e a pessoa que se diverte é a mesma, os pronome têm de concordar:

> Usa a imaginação para **os** imaginar **se** divertindo
>
> Usa a imaginação para **nos** imaginar **nos** divertindo
>
> Usa a imaginação para imaginar  **a gente se** divertindo

Possivelmente o que aconteceu no vídeo foi que o falante começou com *nos imaginar* e continuou como se fosse *a gente*.