# "Auxiliando jogadores e técnicos a crescerem" ou "... a crescer"? - Concordância verbal

Tags: sintaxe, concordância-verbal

Eu quero anunciar um serviço para jogadores e técnicos, mas estou na dúvida em relação a concordância verbal das seguintes frases:

- Auxiliando jogadores e técnicos a crescer(em).
- Auxiliando jogadores e técnicos a crescer(em) como profissionais.
- Auxiliando jogadores e técnicos a crescer(em) seu time.
- Auxiliando jogadores e técnicos a crescer(em) seus jogos.

A dúvida é: deve-se usar "crescer" ou "crescerem" nesses exemplos?

Comment: Relacionado: [Infinitivo pessoal ou impessoal?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1498/2764).

Comment: Em tempo: A quarta frase, "crescer seus jogos", me soa estranha, apesar de compreensível; e similarmente para a terceira, que me parece significar, a rigor, algo como "aumentar o número de jogadores".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entendendo o "a crescer[em]" como complemento, o infinitivo não é flexionado e se teria "**a crescer**" em todos os casos, como colocado pelo [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/concordancia-verbal-com-verbos-no-infinitivo/) e pelo [G1](https://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/o-uso-do-infinitivo.html):

> Não há flexão quando o verbo no infinitivo tem regência de uma preposição, assumido a função de complemento do substantivo, do adjetivo ou do verbo na oração.
>
> - Foram obrigados a passar fome por causa da crise financeira.
> - Aquelas palavras são difíceis de ler.
> - Fui impedida de dar minha opinião.
>
> ---
>
> Quando o infinitivo desempenha a função de complemento,
> usamos a forma não flexionada (=singular):
> “Os paulistanos foram obrigados A PASSAR quatro horas no saguão do aeroporto.”
> “A falta de informação leva outros meninos A FAZER a mesma coisa todos os dias.”
> “A lei proíbe os brasileiros DE FUMAR na ponte aérea.”
> “Os músicos foram impedidos DE PARTICIPAR de qualquer tipo de trabalho em discos.”

Por outro lado há gramáticas (como a indicada noutra [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9295/2764)) que aceitam a flexão, e alguns de seus exemplos soam bem aos meus ouvidos também — e.g., "Ele persuadiu-nos a desistirmos da queixa." e "Incentivámos as crianças a brincarem umas com as outras." — me levando a concordar com o Artefacto que ambas as possibilidades podem ser corretas.

Answer (score 3):

No meu julgamento, ambas as formas são possíveis, embora prefira a opção com o infinitivo não flexionado.

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (vol. II, pág. 1944) diz o seguinte na secção "Verbos que determinam controlo pelo complemento direto da oração subordinante":

> Para a maioria dos falantes, os verbos que regem a preposição *a* selecionam também uma oração subordinada finita ou de um infinitivo flexionado com um sujeito pronominal nulo que... tem como antecedente o complemento direto da oração subordinante:
> a. O professor aconselhou-te a que concorresses/a concorreres a uma bolsa.
> b. Ele persuadiu-nos a que desistíssemos/a desistirmos da queixa.
> c. Incentivámos as crianças a que brincassem/a brincarem umas com as outras.

Da mesma forma teríamos:

> Auxiliando jogadores e técnicos a que cresçam/a crescerem.

Para dizer a verdade, não me soa extremamente bem com *auxiliar* / *ajudar* (a Gramática tem a ressalva "para a maioria dos falantes", afinal de contas), mas é possível encontrar exemplos no CETEMPúblico, como estes:

> par=ext344185-pol-92a-1: Como podemos ajudar os nossos filhos a que cresçam em liberdade e os possamos animar com o nosso exemplo a que sejam generosos com Deus?
> par=ext1020561-nd-91b-1: «Convosco, peço a Deus que nos ajude em cada dia a sermos menos indignos de tão heróico testemunho dos nossos irmãos de Timor. "

Comment: Bom exemplo do valor de checar uma gramática impressa. Especialmente no exemplo (c) de fato me parece melhor flexionado. Atualizei minha resposta com referência a tua.